# How to set Azure Blob Storage CORS properties using Node?

Tags: node.js, azure

I have been following the [blob service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh452235.aspx) and [authentication documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx) in order to set the CORS properties on my azure blob storage account from my mobile service.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

The server response is:

> The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'JI...Tk=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT
>
> x-ms-date:Wed, 19 Feb 2014 07:24:06 GMT x-ms-version:2013-08-15
>   /apporotest/?comp=properties'

When I log the string to sign (not passing contentMD5 and content type) on my end, it turns out to be the same string. So I guess my function to build the shared key is wrong.

**This should build : Base64(HMAC-SHA256(UTF8(StringToSign))):**

```
function buildSharedKeyLite( verb, contentMD5, contentType, canonicalizedHeaders, canonicalizedResource ) {

        var stringToSign = verb + "\n" +
            contentMD5 + "\n" +
            contentType + "\n" +
            "" + "\n" + // date is to be empty because we use x-ms-date
            canonicalizedHeaders +
            canonicalizedResource;

        return crypto.createHmac('sha256', self.accountKey).update(encodeURIComponent(stringToSign)).digest('base64');
    }
```

What confuses me though is that the formerly mentioned documentation for the Shared Key Lite requires MD5 of the content as well as the content type to be set. However, the server response with the string to sign does not seem to expect these.

**If the creation of the shared key lite is correct, then I assume I am not handling the creation of the MD-5 content correctly or the canonicalized headers:**

```
function setCors( cors ) {

        var url = MY_ACCOUNT_UTL + '/?restype=service&comp=properties';
        var canonicalizedResource = '/' + MY_ACCOUNT_NAME + '/?comp=properties';
        var corsMD5 = crypto.createHash('md5' ).update(MY_CORS_XML).digest('base64');
        var date = (new Date()).toUTCString();
        var headers = {

            'x-ms-version': '2013-08-15',
            'x-ms-date': date,
            'Host': MY_ACCOUNT_HOST
        };

        var canonicalizedHeaders = buildCanonicalizedHeaders( headers );

    // THIS
        var key = buildSharedKeyLite( 'PUT', corsMD5, 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8', canonicalizedHeaders, canonicalizedResource );

    // AND THIS, BOTH YIELD THE SAME SERVER RESPONSE    
    var key = buildSharedKeyLite( 'PUT', "", "", canonicalizedHeaders, canonicalizedResource );

        headers['Authorization'] = 'SharedKeyLite ' + MY_ACCOUNT_NAME + ':' + key;

        var options = {
            url: url,
            headers: headers
        };

        function onPropertiesSet(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 202) {
                console.log("CORS: OK");
            }
            else {
                console.log("CORS: "+ response.statusCode);
                console.log(body);
            }
        }
        request.put(options, onPropertiesSet); // require('request')
    }

    function buildCanonicalizedHeaders( headers ) {

        var xmsHeaders = [];
        var canHeaders = "";

        for ( var name in headers ) {
            if ( name.indexOf('x-ms-') == 0 ) )
                xmsHeaders.push( name );
            }
        }

        xmsHeaders.sort();

        for ( var i = 0; i < xmsHeaders.length; i++ ) {
            name = xmsHeaders[i];
            canHeaders = canHeaders + name.toLowerCase().trim() + ':' + headers[name] + '\n';
        }
        return canHeaders;
    }
```

I am really thankful for any pointers.

Comment: hi, can you update the right answer. I really need this too. many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but I believe `encodeURIComponent` is creating problem for you. For example, look at the code below:

```
var a = "PUT\n\n\nFeb 2014 09:08:18 GMT\nx-ms-version:2013-08-15\n/cynapta/?comp=properties";
var b = encodeURIComponent(a);
console.log(a);
console.log("\n");
console.log(b);
```

and this is how `a` and `b` are displayed on my console:

[image]

Can you try by removing `encodeURIComponent` and just pass `stringToSign` directly for signature calculation?

**Update**

Looking at the source code [`here`](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/common/lib/services/hmacsha256sign.js) for signing the request and assuming you're passing storage account key as string, can you try the following in your `buildSharedKeyLite` function:

```
return crypto.createHmac('sha256', new Buffer(self.accountKey, 'base64')).update(stringToSign).digest('base64');
```

Comment: Gaurav - thanks for your input. I actually tried both before, but double checked now. This leads to the same result and server response. I however see 3 newlines in your string after the verb. So I assume you leave contentMD5 and content type blank and do not even add the date.

Comment: Wrong assumption. You actually use date, but no x-ms-date.

Comment: Updated my answer. To answer other question, yes I have left contentMD5 and content type blank. Regarding the date, I have not passed date rather I'm using `x-ms-date`. You can use either of them.

Comment: Thanks for your continued support on this! I now get this error message: "The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format." I also tried passing 'utf-8' as a second parameter to update() as done in the link you referenced above. Both show the same result. Now I assume this means that either the authorization header is wrong and it was correctly encoded before this change. Or one of the other headers is wrong. I'll check using Date instead of x-ms-date.

Comment: And yes - I do pass the accountKey as string. I get it from the app properties which are configured in the Mobile Service portal. I also double checked now that I use the correct (first) key.

Comment: Gaurav - I owe you :) Your updated crypto method (including 'utf-8' as mentioned above) plus setting content-type and length headers and passing the properties XML as request body solved the problem.