# windows azure : set blob CORS properties using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure, blob, cors, azure-blob-storage

REST API has been released in february to set blob [CORS property](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/02/03/windows-azure-storage-introducing-cors.aspx), but this hasn't been implemented for NodeJS yet.

Since I need this feature, I tried to implement it in a module for my azure website running NodeJS.

Based on REST API documentation [to change CORS properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh452235.aspx) and to [generate authentification key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx), on [this](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/a19b6f1e91d134dd13f260b21c10aa7612f0e8fc/lib/services/blob/sharedkeylite.js) implementation of authentification key generation using NodeJS, I tried to follow the accepted answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874694/how-to-set-azure-blob-storage-cors-properties-using-node) post, but it didn't work for me.

Here is what I've got in setcrosproperties.js :

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var request = require('request');


exports.setCors = function (MY_ACCOUNT_URL, MY_ACCOUNT_NAME, MY_ACCOUNT_HOST, accountKey) {
    var MY_CORS_XML =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
        '<StorageServiceProperties>'+
            '<Cors>'+
                '<CorsRule>'+
                    '<AllowedOrigins>*</AllowedOrigins>'+
                    '<AllowedMethods>GET,PUT</AllowedMethods>'+
                    '<MaxAgeInSeconds>500</MaxAgeInSeconds>'+
                    '<ExposedHeaders>x-ms-meta-data*,x-ms-meta-customheader</ExposedHeaders>'+
                    '<AllowedHeaders>x-ms-meta-target*,x-ms-meta-customheader</AllowedHeaders>'+
                '</CorsRule>'+
            '</Cors>'+
            '<DefaultServiceVersion>2013-08-15</DefaultServiceVersion>'+
        '</StorageServiceProperties>';


    var url = MY_ACCOUNT_URL + '/?restype=service&comp=properties';
    var canonicalizedResource = '/' + MY_ACCOUNT_NAME + '/?comp=properties';
    var corsMD5 = crypto.createHash('md5' ).update(MY_CORS_XML).digest('base64');
    var date = (new Date()).toUTCString();
    var headers = {
        'x-ms-version': '2013-08-15',
        'x-ms-date': date,
        'Host': MY_ACCOUNT_HOST
    };

    var canonicalizedHeaders = buildCanonicalizedHeaders( headers );

    // THIS
    var key = buildSharedKeyLite( 'PUT', corsMD5, 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8', canonicalizedHeaders, canonicalizedResource, accountKey);

    // AND THIS, BOTH YIELD THE SAME SERVER RESPONSE
    // var key = buildSharedKeyLite( 'PUT', "", "", canonicalizedHeaders, canonicalizedResource, accountKey);

    headers['Authorization'] = 'SharedKeyLite ' + MY_ACCOUNT_NAME + ':' + key;

    var options = {
        url: url,
        body: MY_CORS_XML,
        headers: headers
    };

    console.log("url : " + url);
    console.log("canonicalizedResource : " + canonicalizedResource);
    console.log("canonicalizedHeaders : " + canonicalizedHeaders);
    console.log("corsMD5 : " + corsMD5);
    console.log("key : " + key);
    console.log("options : " + JSON.stringify(options));

    function onPropertiesSet(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 202) {
            console.log("CORS: OK");
        }
        else {
            console.log("CORS: " + response.statusCode);
            console.log("body : " + body);
        }
    }
    request.put(options, onPropertiesSet); // require('request')
};

function buildCanonicalizedHeaders( headers ) {

    var xmsHeaders = [];
    var canHeaders = "";

    for ( var name in headers ) {
        if ( name.indexOf('x-ms-') == 0 ) {
            xmsHeaders.push( name );
        }
    }

    xmsHeaders.sort();

    for ( var i = 0; i < xmsHeaders.length; i++ ) {
        name = xmsHeaders[i];
        canHeaders = canHeaders + name.toLowerCase().trim() + ':' + headers[name] + '\n';
    }
    return canHeaders;
}

function buildSharedKeyLite( verb, contentMD5, contentType, canonicalizedHeaders, canonicalizedResource, accountKey) {

    var stringToSign = verb + "\n" +
        contentMD5 + "\n" +
        contentType + "\n" +
        "" + "\n" + // date is to be empty because we use x-ms-date
        canonicalizedHeaders +
        canonicalizedResource;

    // return crypto.createHmac('sha256', accountKey).update(encodeURIComponent(stringToSign)).digest('base64');
    return crypto.createHmac('sha256', new Buffer(accountKey, 'base64')).update(stringToSign).digest('base64');
}
```

And here is how I call this function from my server.js file :

```
var setcrosproperties = require('./setcrosproperties.js');
// setCors(MY_ACCOUNT_URL, MY_ACCOUNT_NAME, MY_ACCOUNT_HOST, accountKey)
setcrosproperties.setCors(
    'https://'+process.env['AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT']+'.blob.core.windows.net',
    process.env['AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT'],
    process.env['AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT']+'.blob.core.windows.net',
    process.env['AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY']);
```

I did not understand what was the difference intended with variables MY_ACCOUNT_UTL (I assumed URL) and MY_ACCOUNT_HOST, so I use the same value for both parameters of the function.

(I removed the "cors" parameter, which seemed to be unused.)

Here is what I get in the console :

> url : https://NAME_OF_MY_STORAGE_ACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/?restype=service&comp=properties
>   canonicalizedResource : /NAME_OF_MY_STORAGE_ACCOUNT/?comp=properties
>   canonicalizedHeaders : x-ms-date:Sun, 09 Mar 2014 12:33:41 GMT
>   x-ms-version:2013-08-15
>   corsMD5 : +ij...w==
>   key : sNB...JrY=
>   options : {"url":"https://NAME_OF_MY_STORAGE_ACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/?restype=service&comp=properties","body":"*GET,PUT500x-ms-meta-data*,x-ms-meta-customheaderx-ms-meta-target*,x-ms-meta-customheader2013-08-15","headers":{"x-ms-version":"2013-08-15","x-ms-date":"Sun, 09 Mar 2014 12:33:41 GMT","Host":"NAME_OF_MY_STORAGE_ACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net","Authorization":"SharedKeyLite NAME_OF_MY_STORAGE_ACCOUNT:sNB...rY="}}
>   CORS: 403
>   body : ﻿`AuthenticationFailed`Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
>   RequestId:1e6abfe3-e0e8-4b9c-922d-7cb34485eec9
>   Time:2014-03-09T12:33:41.7262308ZThe MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'sNB...JrY=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT
>
> x-ms-date:Sun, 09 Mar 2014 12:33:41 GMT
>   x-ms-version:2013-08-15
>   /NAME_OF_MY_STORAGE_ACCOUNT/?comp=properties'.

Any idea about what I am doing wrong here? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `Content-Type` and `Content-MD5` in your `headers` array and that should do the trick. Here's the modified code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var request = require('request');


exports.setCors = function (MY_ACCOUNT_URL, MY_ACCOUNT_NAME, MY_ACCOUNT_HOST, accountKey) {
    var MY_CORS_XML =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
        '<StorageServiceProperties>'+
            '<Cors>'+
                '<CorsRule>'+
                    '<AllowedOrigins>*</AllowedOrigins>'+
                    '<AllowedMethods>GET,PUT</AllowedMethods>'+
                    '<MaxAgeInSeconds>500</MaxAgeInSeconds>'+
                    '<ExposedHeaders>x-ms-meta-data*,x-ms-meta-customheader</ExposedHeaders>'+
                    '<AllowedHeaders>x-ms-meta-target*,x-ms-meta-customheader</AllowedHeaders>'+
                '</CorsRule>'+
            '</Cors>'+
            '<DefaultServiceVersion>2013-08-15</DefaultServiceVersion>'+
        '</StorageServiceProperties>';


    var url = MY_ACCOUNT_URL + '/?restype=service&comp=properties';
    var canonicalizedResource = '/' + MY_ACCOUNT_NAME + '/?comp=properties';
    var corsMD5 = crypto.createHash('md5' ).update(MY_CORS_XML).digest('base64');
    var date = (new Date()).toUTCString();
    var headers = {
        'x-ms-version': '2013-08-15',
        'x-ms-date': date,
        'Host': MY_ACCOUNT_HOST,
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',//Added this line
        'Content-MD5': corsMD5,//Added this line
    };

    var canonicalizedHeaders = buildCanonicalizedHeaders( headers );

    // THIS
    var key = buildSharedKeyLite( 'PUT', corsMD5, 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8', canonicalizedHeaders, canonicalizedResource, accountKey);

    // AND THIS, BOTH YIELD THE SAME SERVER RESPONSE
    // var key = buildSharedKeyLite( 'PUT', "", "", canonicalizedHeaders, canonicalizedResource, accountKey);

    headers['Authorization'] = 'SharedKeyLite ' + MY_ACCOUNT_NAME + ':' + key;

    var options = {
        url: url,
        body: MY_CORS_XML,
        headers: headers
    };

    console.log("url : " + url);
    console.log("canonicalizedResource : " + canonicalizedResource);
    console.log("canonicalizedHeaders : " + canonicalizedHeaders);
    console.log("corsMD5 : " + corsMD5);
    console.log("key : " + key);
    console.log("options : " + JSON.stringify(options));

    function onPropertiesSet(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 202) {
            console.log("CORS: OK");
        }
        else {
            console.log("CORS: " + response.statusCode);
            console.log("body : " + body);
        }
    }
    request.put(options, onPropertiesSet); // require('request')
};

function buildCanonicalizedHeaders( headers ) {

    var xmsHeaders = [];
    var canHeaders = "";

    for ( var name in headers ) {
        if ( name.indexOf('x-ms-') == 0 ) {
            xmsHeaders.push( name );
        }
    }

    xmsHeaders.sort();

    for ( var i = 0; i < xmsHeaders.length; i++ ) {
        name = xmsHeaders[i];
        canHeaders = canHeaders + name.toLowerCase().trim() + ':' + headers[name] + '\n';
    }
    return canHeaders;
}

function buildSharedKeyLite( verb, contentMD5, contentType, canonicalizedHeaders, canonicalizedResource, accountKey) {

    var stringToSign = verb + "\n" +
        contentMD5 + "\n" +
        contentType + "\n" +
        "" + "\n" + // date is to be empty because we use x-ms-date
        canonicalizedHeaders +
        canonicalizedResource;

    // return crypto.createHmac('sha256', accountKey).update(encodeURIComponent(stringToSign)).digest('base64');
    return crypto.createHmac('sha256', new Buffer(accountKey, 'base64')).update(stringToSign).digest('base64');
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Gaurav ! It solved the problem on server side ! So now, thanks to you, I can change my blob cors properties. But my client application still can't access it

Comment: It gests the following error while trying to push a file to the blob :

OPTIONS https://MYSTORAGEACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/publicblobssas/88570e7e-d6…cdbLaTjhlHGag0L3slFVJbXgMFXlWnfXmsU%3D&comp=block&blockid=YmxvY2stMDAwMDAw 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)

Comment: OPTIONS https://MYSTORAGEACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/publicblobssas/88570e7e-d6…XlWnfXmsU%3D&comp=block&blockid=YmxvDAw No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fileuploaderblob.azurewebsites.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://MYSTORAGEACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/publicblobssas/88570e7e-d6…cXmsU%3D&comp=block&blockid=Ymxvst. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fileuploaderblob.azurewebsites.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Here are the header I use for every answer from my server : 

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'x-ms-*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
    next();
});

Do you have an idea about what is wrong ?

Comment: One thing we realized is that each browser sends different request headers apart from the request headers you're trying to send. I would recommend setting `*` in `<AllowedHeaders></AllowedHeaders>` so that all headers are entertained.

Comment: Good idea. So I changed my headers in cors settings : var MY_CORS_XML =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
'<StorageServiceProperties>'+
    '<Cors>'+
        '<CorsRule>'+
            '<AllowedOrigins>*</AllowedOrigins>'+
            '<AllowedMethods>GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS</AllowedMethods>'+
            '<MaxAgeInSeconds>5000</MaxAgeInSeconds>'+
            '<ExposedHeaders>*</ExposedHeaders>'+
            '<AllowedHeaders>*</AllowedHeaders>'+
        '</CorsRule>'+
    '</Cors>'+
    '<DefaultServiceVersion>2013-08-15</DefaultServiceVersion>'+
'</StorageServiceProperties>';

Comment: and I also changed the headers of responses I serve the client : 
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Exposed-Headers", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
    next();
});

Comment: May I suggest you post this as another question instead of adding as comment. It will be easier to answer that way. Please post your complete client side JS code. HTH.

Comment: ok, here it is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385527/pushing-a-file-to-azure-blob-storage-using-sas-and-cors-properties. Thanks for helping so much

Comment: Ok, I found the final trick. Your answer was perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

To configure CORS, use the Azure storage library for Node.js.

You can do `npm install azure-storage` to get it. Source code is at https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node.

The one that come with npm package [`azure`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/azure) (a.k.a. `azure-sdk-for-node`) use older [`azure-storage-legacy`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/azure-storage-legacy) package, which does not support CORS.

You can set the CORS with the following code:

```
var service = azure.createBlobService();
var serviceProperties = {
  Cors: {
    CorsRule: [{
      AllowedOrigins: ['*'],
      AllowedMethods: ['GET'],
      AllowedHeaders: [],
      ExposedHeaders: [],
      MaxAgeInSeconds: 60
    }]
  }
}; 


service.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties, callback);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome.. for completeness the method is called like: `service.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties, callback);` where `serviceProperties = {Cors: {CorsRule: [{AllowedOrigins: [*], ...}]}}`;
For more details on required properties illustrated by "..." above see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh452235.aspx

Comment: Can you please add the complete answer?